# SSIS grab Sharepoint Excel file, won't work on server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssis

I have Sharepoint 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2, and Windows Server 2008 R2 and a Windows 7 laptop.

So on my laptop, I have a file in a Sharepoint library, and I made a very simple package with 1 task (File System Task) to move a file from the Sharepoint list directly to another location server.  It works perfectly on my laptop.  The source connection is something like this:
\oursharepoint.com\DavWWWRoot\sites\directoryIneed\subdirectoryIneed\manymoresubdirectories\fileIneed.xlsx

When I try this on the location on the server, the server cannot find the location.  In the source connection manager, I place the path in, and press "browse" and it does not seem to be able to locate the directory.  I am logged into the server as me, and I can open up the Sharepoint file in IE.  I get an error saying "Windows cannot access ... check spelling. Otherwise there might be a problem with your network..."  When I press 'Diagnose' Windows Network Diagnostics says "The device or resource (oursharepoint.com) is not set up to accept connections on port "The File and Printer Sharing (SMB)"

How can I resolve this?

I guess I could just run it from my computer and figure out how to schedule it to work automatically.  But that is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david/archive/2010/07/20/getting-sharepoint-folder-views-working-on-windows-2008.aspx.
If your still facing issues after tweaking the above then check to make sure the process Id you are running your job under has access to share point.